# How do I completely uninstall IntelliJ Idea Community 2017.1 from Ubuntu 16.04 using command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, uninstallation

I need to uninstall and reinstall IntelliJ Community 2017.1 from my Linux machine. I have removed the tar.gz files and hidden files in my home directory, but I still find an idea.sh file when searching my computer. Does anyone have a full and complete set of command line instructions for removing all files completely? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question already has the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/300692.